# LuaLaTeX: option clash for package graphicx when loaded after fontspec

Tags: graphics, luatex, fontspec

I don't know if it is stated in any documentation somewhere, but I can't figure out why I can't compile this MWE when `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`is loaded after `\usepackage{fontspec}`

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    Text
\end{document}
```

with error

> Option clash for package graphicx

However, loading `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` before `\usepackage{fontspec}` makes the compilation go smooth as in

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: xunicode (loaded by fontspec) load graphicx without option.

Comment: `fontspec` loads `xunicode` which, in turn, loads `graphicx`. So you need to load `graphicx` earlier, if you want to pass options to it.

Comment: Really `draft` isn't meant as an option for individual packages (other than as a pass-through): it's meant to be given globally

Comment: @JosephWright So, if I want to compile the whole document with printing images placeholders (i.e. suppressing the images), how can I do it?

Comment: @JosephWright Not quite. Package pdfx needs to load hyperref, and hyperref must be in draft mode for PDF/X-1a. Reason is that x-1a does not allow hyperlinks. In other words, putting hyperref in draft mode, even for a final document, is a way of using just a portion of hyperref code. On the other hand, microtype is often used in final mode, even in a draft document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package `fontspec` loads `fontspec-luatex.sty`, if used with LuaTeX. Then package `xunicode` is loaded that loads package `graphicx` *without* options.

The LaTeX reaches `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`. The package is already loaded. Therefore, LaTeX only checks the options. If there is any new option (here: `draft`) it throws the error message.

Solutions:

- Load package `graphicx` with all needed options before `\usepackage{fontspec}` as in the question.
- `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}` *before* `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: I am sorry, but should  your second solution state passing the option after loading `fontspec` not before as you wrote?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Then it is too late. At the *first* real loading of the package, *all* options have to be given to the package. If the package is again loaded later, then a subset of the first option set works fine, but any new options causes an error (the only exception is package `fontenc`).

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t place the draft option in the documentclass command?

Comment: @HerbSchulz If option `draft` is given to the document class, then it will also be passed to other packages. That might not be, what the OP wants (marking of overfull boxes, no links in case of `hyperref`, ...).

Answer (score 7):

If you load `fontspec` with the `tuenc` option (which should become the default in the near future), there is no problem:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    Text
\end{document}
```

Otherwise, load `graphicx` (with options) before `fontspec`.

Comment: I appreciate your new-to-me input. However, could you tell me, in a nutshell, what `tuenc` option does?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou one main thing it does (by design) is not load graphics

Comment: @DiaaAbidou `fontspec` uses `xunicode` “because it was there”; a proper implementation with a new output encoding is with `TU`.